# How to get the date of "this Wednesday", "this Thursday" etc. in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I know that Rails has an elegant way of getting dates for a certain day of the week for next week, or for last week ([docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-next_week)).

```rb
today = Time.zone.today
=> Fri, 24 Jan 2020

today.next_week
=> Mon, 27 Jan 2020 # Gets Monday by default

today.next_week(:thursday)
=> Thu, 30 Jan 2020 # You can get a certain day of the week by passing it in as an argument
```

Is there a way to do the same for this week? For example, getting the date of this Thursday, Friday, etc.? Right now, my workaround is to get the date of `beginning_of_week` (Monday) and calculate from there. Ideally, I wanted to do something similar to above, like `Time.zone.today.this_week(:thursday)`.

```rb
this_monday = Time.zone.today.beginning_of_week
=> Mon, 20 Jan 2020

this_friday = this_monday.since(4.days).to_date
=> Fri, 24 Jan 2020
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `#next_occurring`

```
pry(main)> Time.zone.today.beginning_of_week
Mon, 20 Jan 2020
pry(main)> Time.zone.today.beginning_of_week.next_occurring(:thursday)
Thu, 23 Jan 2020
```

Comment: Thank you. `.next_occurring` is somewhat easier to read than `.since(4.days)` (while still pretty verbose).

Comment: There's also `Time.zone.today.beginning_of_week(:thursday)`, but from the docs it's not clear to me if that really does what you want to achieve and it feels more like a hack. Personally, I would't use that in production code, so I did not include it in my answer.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, please mark it as such.

Comment: This worked for me as well `Time.parse('10:30:00').in_time_zone('Europe/London').next_occurring(:thursday)`